# dynamic_cast failure while calling C++ API from Python

Tags: c++, python

I am attempting to call a C++ API from python. Following is the code in the pseudo form.

```
class Engine { // Singleton Class which does a heavy duty work
public:
    static Engine* getEngine();
    bool init();
private:
    static Engine* m_instance;
    Engine();
};

// Following the code to wrap the call to engine to call from python
// Its only a simplified form

//engine_module.c
#include <Engine.h>
PyObject* initengine() {
    Engine* e = Engine::getInstance();
    e->init();
   // return the Py_BuildValue ...   
}

PyObject* initengine_module() {
//... init the module
}

// Python code
import engine_module
status = engine_module.init()
```

**Problem:**
The Engine class is in libengine.so and when it inits it fails because internally dynamic_cast fails. The Engine in turns loads other libraries using dlopen(). I searched the net to add RTDL_GLOBAL and -E option while linking but still its not resolved. Am I supposed to add the -E option while compiling the python itself? 
What could be the reason that Engine class works perfectly well when used in C++ code and does not work when used in python?

**Edit 1:** 
To clarify on the question from Cat++: 
libengine.so has many other classes which internally in Engine::init() uses dynamic_cast<>. The classes involved in dynamic_cast are not exposed to python at all. Only the Engine::init() is exposed.

**Edit 2:**
The platform is Red Hat Linux and the compiler is Intel

Comment: None of this code has `dynamic_cast` in it. Also, don't use singletons.

Comment: libengine.so has many other classes which internally in Engine::init() uses dynamic_cast<>. The classes involved in dynamic_cast are not exposed to python at all. Only the Engine::init() is exposed.

Comment: Does it work if you make a test-program in C++, and call `Engine::init`?

Comment: @Sudeep: So what? Supposedly `dynamic_cast` is what fails, which makes all of this code more or less irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, libengine.so is an existing one and it works very well.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: The engine loads a class XYZ from another library say libanother.so. Its derived from class ABC which is in libengine.so. The dynamic_cast converting ABC* to XYZ* fails. Question is where to add the -E linker flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is how and when the dynamic library are loaded.  The code
you show in engine_module.c references `Engine`, so the library with
`Engine` will be automatically loaded *before* any of the initialization
code in `engine_module.c` is executed.  Similarly, any libraries used by
`Engine` will be loaded before the library with `Engine` is loaded.  All
of which will be loaded using the flags Python used to load its
interface module.  (`RTDL_LOCAL` is my guess.)  Any `dlopen` you invoke
later will find that the module has already been loaded, and ignore the
request—including ignoring any options to `dlopen` you might have
passed.

The way we solved this was to create a special loader module, which
contained *no* direct references to any of the other modules.  Python
loads this module, which implements the `initxxx` function.  The
`initxxx` function explicitly loads all of the other modules needed, in
a dependency determined order. (If A used B, B will be loaded before A.)
With `RTDL_GLOBAL`, of course.  In your case, this would be the
libraries used by `Engine`, then `Engine`.  The last module to be loaded
would be the one with the Python interface; we put the Python
initialization code in the constructor of a static object, so it would
be executed automatically when the object was loaded, but you can also
put it in a named function, as long as you get the address of this
function using `dlsym`, rather than declaring it `extern` in any
fashion.  The important thing is to ensure that all of the libraries are first loaded by your explicit `dlopen`, and not implicitly as a result of an undefined external in some library loaded earlier.

Comment: Thanks James, I will certainly try this and post the results here.

Comment: I loaded the libengine.so using dlopen the moment my python module is loaded and this works beautifully. There was no need to add the -E flag for the linker. I will be writing a small blog to explain this step by step and a link to this page. Thanks a lot James.

Comment: @Sudeep I'd forgotten to mention that we didn't use the `-E` option either.  And that as far as I know, it only affects linking of executables, not of shared libraries.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that your are trying to apply `dynamic_cast` to some non-polymorphic classes and that's where it fails. Remember that `dynamic_cast` works only for classes with at least one virtual method (destructor counts).

Comment: Fair enough. However, the base class in question have virtual functions.